# boost::locale 1.57.0 with ICU library 54.1 under Windows (VC++ 2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8.1, build-process, icu, boost-locale

I'm trying to build Boost::locale 1.57.0 with ICU library support 54.1 under Windows 8.1. I have the library on C:\icu with files like these:

```
C:\icu\lib64

icudt.exp
icudt.lib
icuin.exp
icuin.lib
icuio.exp
icuio.lib
...

C:\icu\include\unicode
C:\icu\include\layout
...
```

I ran the following:

```
$ bootstrap

$ .\b2 -sICU_PATH=C:\icu -j4 --toolset=msvc-10.0 address-model=64 --build-type=complete stage
```

But then I got the following messages:

```
- zlib                     : no
- iconv (libc)             : no
- iconv (separate)         : no
- icu                      : no
- icu (lib64)              : no
- message-compiler         : yes
```

These messages means that I won't get ICU support at all? What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. But I was able to compile the Boost.Locale with referring [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/locale/doc/html/building_boost_locale.html) . So basically what I did was:

```
bjam --with-locale -sICU_PATH=C:\icu stage link=static,shared
```

It found ICU and was able to create `static` and `shared` files. 
Hope this helps.